# How to access component value programmatically

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Lets assume I want to access the value of a sibling component in an ActionListener.

The following fragment is not working as expected, resulting in a ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.String

```
public void processAction(final ActionEvent event) {

    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIComponent sibling = event.getComponent().findComponent("inputText");

    String value = (String) sibling.getValue();
    ...
}
```

If I change the essential part to the following fragment everything works fine:

```
String value = ctx.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(ctx, inputText.getValueExpression("value").getExpressionString(), String.class);
```

Is there a nicer solution? Why is the value of the inputText of type HashSet?

Thx in advance

Comment: First fragment should work. What is 'inputText' and what is it's value  in your jsf code?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete description. "inputText" is the id of a <h:inputText> that is located besides the CommandLink. Im using this construct within a compositeComponent but afaik that should not have any effect on the <h:inputText>. Here is the view definition:  
<composite:implementation>  
<h:commandLink id="actionLink" value="send" actionListener="#{bean.listener}"/>  
<h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" />  
</composite:implementation>

Comment: Can't reproduce this. An SSCCE would be helpful. Please tell as wel what JSF and appserver impl/version you're using.